# receiving blank response from CURL while receiving large JSON data from API

Tags: php, json, curl, buffer

Im making a call to API using CURL in PHP, and when the JSON response from API is lengthy, curl response is going blank, I accessed the API via URL on browser that is working, is there a content size limit? tried increasing buffer size but no luck.
the same code works when the response content is small.
any ideas why this is happening